# How to add more images to parallax image code

Tags: jquery, html

I came across a code that works fine on tumblr , I just wanted to know how to add more images to it ? It's a Parallax code where the image moves slightly w/ the movement of the mouse , but I wanted 3 images to be present instead of one . I've tried adding two images and playing with the Javascript , but instead one image wouldn't move and the other one would . I want all three images to move with the cursor and have a smooth movement to them .  Like this:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Interactive-Background-Parallax-Effect-With-jQuery-CSS3/

```
<div style='height:30px;clear:both;text-align:center;'>Mouse over image area.</div>
<div style='height:400px;width:400px;text-align:center;'>
<img id='myImage' src='http://img516.imageshack.us/img516/7355/icon.png' style='position:absolute' />
```

```
<script>
var tempX = 0;
var tempY = 0;
var oldTempX = 0;
var oldTempY = 0;
var IE =  !!(window.attachEvent&&!window.opera);

function shiftImageXY(e) {
 if (IE) { 
tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
 } else {  
tempX = e.pageX;
tempY = e.pageY;
 }  
 img = document.getElementById('myImage');
 speedFactorDamping = 0.1; // change this for faster movement
 xdir = (tempX - oldTempX) ;
 ydir = (tempY - oldTempY) ;
 parallexX = -xdir*speedFactorDamping;
 parallexY = -ydir*speedFactorDamping;
 currX = parseInt(img.offsetLeft);
 currY = parseInt(img.offsetTop);

 img.style.left = (currX + parallexX) + 'px';
 img.style.top = (currY + parallexY) + 'px';
 oldTempX = tempX;
 oldTempY = tempY;
 return true;
}

 document.onmousemove = shiftImageXY;


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [example you linked](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Interactive-Background-Parallax-Effect-With-jQuery-CSS3/) will work correctly for multiple images if you apply the `bg` class (you can rename that if you're not using the images as backgrounds).

This is bit messy as I hack'n'slashed the existing demo page, but it demonstrates 3 images all moving:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lFollowX = 0,
    lFollowY = 0,
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    friction = 1 / 30;

  function moveBackground() {
    x += (lFollowX - x) * friction;
    y += (lFollowY - y) * friction;

    translate = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px) scale(1.1)';

    $('.bg').css({
      '-webit-transform': translate,
      '-moz-transform': translate,
      'transform': translate
    });

    window.requestAnimationFrame(moveBackground);
  }

  $(window).on('mousemove click', function(e) {
    var lMouseX = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).width() / 2 - e.clientX));
    var lMouseY = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).height() / 2 - e.clientY));
    lFollowX = (20 * lMouseX) / 100;
    lFollowY = (10 * lMouseY) / 100;
  });

  moveBackground();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper1 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
.wrapper2 {
  top: 300px;
  left: 20px;
}
.wrapper3 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 300px;
}
.bg {
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.bg1 {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1800/1600?image=1000");
}
.bg2 {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1800/1600?image=1001");
}
.bg3 {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1800/1600?image=1002");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper wrapper1">
  <div class="bg bg1"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper wrapper2">
  <div class="bg bg2"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper wrapper3">
  <div class="bg bg3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! - This works really well ? I'm grateful that you took the time to help me out with this  . Thank you for explaining .